# How to configure VPN traffic over certain ports only - Windows

Tags: windows, vpn, home-networking, openvpn, network-traffic

I would like to force only certain ports through my VPN (or open only certain ports from my VPN, which ever is easier). I am on windows, and the VPN service has options for OpenVPN, SSTP, L2TP/PPTP. After much googling I have found only a couple solutions - one being to install OpenVPN on my router then SSH in and change the routing. Unfortunately my Linksys (Cisco) E4200 does not have shell access, nor does it allow me to install OpenVPN.

Is there a way within any of the supported VPN options to route certain traffic (port) and not others, or vice versa - either through windows or on my router itself? I have seen the dd-wrt flashing to get rid of my Linksys firmware, which I would be ok with if thats my only option.

I found one thread on the use of OpenVPN client Viscosity which allowed the user to forward his internet traffic (80,440) outside the VPN, but the links on how to configure were dead.  I installed it, but am not sure how to configure it on the 'Networking' tab.